# Show/Hide Gallery

Tags: jquery

I have a gallery that is showing and hiding when you click on a thumbnail that shows in a drop down. http://bvh.delineamultimedia.com/?page_id=2 If you click the first image it drops down and shows the gallery. If you close it and open it again the gallery is no longer there. Is there a way to get it to stay there no matter how many times I click the thumbnail.

This code is suppose to show the gallery if its there else show the thumbnail in a larger format.

```
if (sliderData.length > 0) { // show the slider if there is one
    superbox.append(sliderData); // clone the element so we don't loose it for the next time the user clicks
} else { // if there is no slider proceed as before
    if (imgData.img) {
        superboximg.attr('src', imgData.img);
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably have to reinitialize your slider on each click

Comment: Thats what I was thinking too. Going to have to find out how to do that.

Comment: I'm hoping this might help... http://jsfiddle.net/3hjsy/6/